# Regarding non-equal allocators in STL

Tags: c++, stl

I am reading Item 10 in Effective STL by Scott Meyers on allocators in C++.

> Standard says that an implementation of the STL is permitted to assume
>   that all allocator objects of the same type are equivalent and always
>   compare equal.
>
> That's all well and good, but the more you think about it. the more
>   you'll realize just how draconian a restriction it is that STL
>   implementations may assume that allocators of the same type are
>   equivalent. It means that portable allocator objects — allocators that
>   will function correctly under different STL implementations — may not
>   have state. Let's be explicit about this: it means that portable
>   allocators may not have any nonstatic data members, at least not any
>   that affect their behavior. None. Nada. That means, for example, you
>   can't have one SpecialAllocator that allocates from one heap and
>   a different SpecialAllocator that allocates from a different
>   heap. Such allocators wouldn't be equivalent, and STL implementations
>   exist where attempts to use both allocators could lead to corrupt
>   runtime data structures.
>
> In fairness to the Standardization Committee, I should point out that
>   it included the following statement immediately after the text that
>   permits STL implementers to assume that allocators of the same type
>   are equivalent:
>
> Implementors are encouraged to supply libraries that ... support
>   non-equal instances. In such implementations. ... the semantics of
>   containers and algorithms when allocator instances compare non-equal
>   are implementation-defined.
>
> This is a lovely sentiment, but as a user of the STL who is
>   considering the development of a custom allocator with state, it
>   offers you next to nothing.  You can take advantage of this statement
>   only if (1) you know that the STL implementations you are using
>   support inequivalent allocators, (2) you are willing to delve into
>   their documentation to determine whether the implementation-defined
>   behavior of "non-equal" allocators is acceptable to you, and
>
> (3) you're not concerned about porting your code to STL
>   implementations that may take advantage of the latitude expressly
>   extended to them by the Standard. In short, this paragraph — paragraph
>   5 of section 20.1.5. for those who insist on knowing — is the
>   Standard's "1 have a dream" speech for allocators. Until that dream
>   becomes common reality, programmers concerned about portability will
>   limit themselves to custom allocators with no state.

My question on above paragraph are

1. What does author mean by inequivalent or  non-equal allocators?
2. What does last paragraph in above text i.e, point 3 mean in simple terms?

Answer (score 4):

That information is out of date.  C++11 and later versions support stateful allocators.

The quotes you have posted from Effective C++ are only of concern if you are writing a C++ library which requires custom allocators, does not require C++11, and which supports building against unknown/unspecified standard libraries.  To a first approximation, nobody is doing this anymore.  The people who were doing it before often had their own "enhanced" standard library implementations to support stateful allocators, such as EASTL or BDESTL.

Answer (score 2):

Two allocators should compare equal if memory allocated by one can be freed by the other. So, for example, an allocator object that allocates from a pool that it holds can allocate and free memory from that pool, but a different allocator object that has a different pool can't (without a great deal of extra bookkeeping) free memory allocated by the first object.

Making that work right was beyond what the standards committee wanted to take on when allocators were first introduced, which is why the words were so squishy. And that license has been revoked in more recent versions of the standard.

The last paragraph means that if you write an allocator whose objects rely on internal state (e.g., the pool allocator that I mentioned above), and the library you're using respects the equality operator (as in, it won't try to pass pointers around among allocators that don't compare equal), your code will break when you try to use it with a different implementation that doesn't pay attention to the equality operator.

Comment: Does your answer refer to C++03 or C++11?

Comment: @JohnZwinck -- it refers to the quoted text and the history of allocators.

Comment: Do you mean to say that not equal allocators to work is not required according to standard? Is that right?

Comment: @venkysmarty -- **originally**, standard library implementations were not required to check equality of allocators; as long as they were the same type, the implementation was allowed to treat them as interchangeable. That's what that text is talking about.

Comment: @Pete Becker. Thanks  Now it make sense.